# Comparing two dataframes based on date

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, window-functions

First `df_1` looks like this:

```
 my_id     series         date  category      value       
   000         1    2022-08-10         A      alpha
   100         2    2022-08-10         A      alpha
   101         2    2022-08-10         B       beta
   102         3    2022-08-11         B       vega
   103         3    2022-08-11         C      delta  
   104         4    2022-08-12         B      delta
   105         5    2022-08-13         A       beta 
   106         5    2022-08-13         A        eta
   107         5    2022-08-14         C      alpha
```

Second `df_2` looks like this:

```
 my_id           date  category      value       some_other_columns...
   100     2022-08-10         A      alpha
   101     2022-08-10         B       beta
   102     2022-08-11         B       vega
   104     2022-08-12         B      delta
   107     2022-08-14         C      alpha
```

**Goal**: for the same `date` and same `category`, check which series are not fully contained in `df_2`, but **check only up to the latest `date` of each `category` present in `df_2`.**

I did:

```
def join_inclusion_check(df_2, df_1):

    windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("category", "date") 

    ids = (df_1.withColumn("max_series", F.max("series").over(windowSpec)).filter(F.col("max_series")==F.col("series")).select("ids"))
    output_df = ids.subtract(df_2.select("my_id"))
    return output_df
```

But it would output:

```
  my_id
    103
    105
    106
```

while I just want `103`, because A stopped appearing after 2022-08-10.

Comment: Could you add your expected output?

Comment: @Jonathan OP added it, it’s just one value of the column my_id, 103.

Comment: 103 belongs to C, not A. I can see the gap after A stopped appearing. You could return the missing rows from df_1. But I don't understand why you want 103 and how it is connected to A. Please add more explanations to the question.